# Tailwind CSS responsive classes not working with Laravel and Jetstream

Tags: css, laravel, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="py-2">
   <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 sm:rounded-lg">
      <div class="p-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
         <div class="grid grid-cols-7 md:grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-4 m-1">
            <div class="">c</div>
            <div class="">d</div>
            <div class="">e</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here only `md:grid-cols-3` is showing the divs side by side and if I give anything larger than 3 , like md:grid-cols-4, it is showing the divs each in separate rows. Also, it is not triggering any other breakpoints and so if I select responsive mode in DevTools, I can see the `md:grid-cols-3` is applied and it is showing the same three grids instead of 2. I am using Tailwind with Laravel and Jetstream

How can I fix this ? Also it is not taking the `grid-cols-7` if `md:grid-cols-3` is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the `md:` overwrites everything bigger than a certain amount of pixels, this is why it is overwriting the `grid-cols-7` because the screen is probably bigger than the set amount of px width. This is also true for the `sm:` this sets a condition like `if screen is bigger in width than x pixels do style` so it will overwrite other styles you are setting basically you can imagine it going from bottom to top.

Comment: If I give `md:grid-cols-4` then it is showing on the next row. That `c,d,e` each on seperate rows. Not in one row with 4 columns.

Comment: Then it seems the `tailwind` `CSS` has a class for `md:grid-cols-3` and not for `md:grid-cols-4` can you find the class in the CSS that is loaded in?

Comment: The classes are there in Tailwind. But seems like for the Laravel and Jetstream, it is missing.

Comment: Then I think in your `build` something is not adding it do you have something like `purgecss` or something that is removing it in build time?